# how SameSite attribute added to my Asp.net_SessionID cookie automatically?

Tags: asp.net, iis, samesite

Recently samesite=lax add automatically to my session cookie!
this attribute just add to sessionID:
`"Set-Cookie  ASP.NET_SessionId=zana3mklplqwewhwvika2125; path=/; HttpOnly; **SameSite=Lax**"`

My website hosted on IIS 8.5, Windows 2012 R2, and dont have WAF or UrlRewrite and I turn off AntiVirus (kasper).

but yet have same problem on some customer servers.

any idea?

**EDITED:**
I Find this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4524419/kb4524419

> ASP.NET will now emit a SameSite cookie header when HttpCookie.SameSite value is 'None' to accommodate upcoming changes to SameSite cookie handling in Chrome. As part of this change, FormsAuth and SessionState cookies will also be issued with SameSite = 'Lax' instead of the previous default of 'None', though these values can be overridden in web.config.

How can i overridde samesite cookies for SessionState in web.config?
i add this line, but it not work on SessionID cookie!
`<httpCookies sameSite="Unspecified" />`

**EDITED:** I find this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookiesamesite?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_SessionStateSection_CookieSameSite

Set samesite for stateserver by "cookieSameSite" attribute of SessionState tag.

Comment: Have you get it resolved by adding “<sessionstate CookieSameSite"？ I have 4.8 installed but when I access sessionstate section from IIS manager. I just receive  unrecognized attribute.

Comment: i receive same message in iis, but it work and change samesite value in set-cookie time. i add cookieSameSite="None" to my web.config to get previuse behvior. notice that cookieSameSite is caseSesitive.

Comment: I just had to patch a 4.5.2 legacy site for this - SameSite wasn't supported by the configs so I had to intercept the cookie on Session_Start and rewrite it directly with "SameSite=None; Secure" added.

Comment: @ParanoidCoder tank you for your suggest, i use .net 4.6.1 and it works for me. But i have a question about your solution: you use URL rewrite (extension of IIS) or you rewrite it by code in Session_Start, can you show me your code?

Comment: @ParanoidCoder Yes, can you please share Session_Start code?

Comment: @Sadegh Which one you used to overcome on a problem ?

Comment: @VaibhavDeshmukh i add cookieSameSite to sessionState. (same as accepted answer)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't use rewrite, because UrlRewrite not installed on all my customers servers.

Finally i add cookieSameSite to my web.config:

```html
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieSameSite="None" sqlConnectionString="data source=(local);user id=sa;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry @Sadegh.K, but it will not work before 4.7.2 as stated here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite#using-samesite-in-aspnet-472-and-48

Comment: @cederlof i found this : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4533011/kb4533011

Comment: @Sadegh Right, but that doesn't add the `cookieSameSite` functionality to web.config - .NET 4.7.2 does. The link I posted in my comment is also linked to from the page you refer to.

Comment: @cederlof i agree with you, but after this update, I add this config to my web.config, and it works for me, and samesite="none" set on my site requests.

Comment: @Sadegh how to set the site to support Net 4.7.2 ?

Comment: @developerlearn999 if you mean how set samesite in .net 4.7.2, just add cookieSameSite to your web.config such as above.

Answer (score 26):

Add these options to web.config for sameSite=None , Lax or Strict

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms cookieSameSite="None" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: `<httpCookies sameSite` is not shown as a valid option on .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: @AnkushJain, no, it is supported since .Net Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: If you want it to work in `sessionState`, make sure that you have the `targetFramework` attribute set in **both** `compilation` and `httpRuntime`: `<system.web><compilation targetFramework="4.7.2"/><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2"/></system.web>`.

Comment: One of my sites is really old .net 3.5. And the website just breaks when i add above. Can we use .htaccess file instead or httpd.ini for that matter? Let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: @IronSean that's VS complaining. That's just MS not updating their tool. The setting does work though.

Comment: @VasiliyZverev what to do for 4.8?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG, ignore VS warning, it works in 4.8.

Answer (score 24):

CookieSameSite attribute is not available for many older frameworks. If you're in the situation where the accepted answer is not supported in your environment, read on!

I modified upon several SO answers to come up with this URL rewrite that adds `SameSite=None` to session cookies, and also remove `SameSite=None` from *all* cookies for most incompatible browsers. The aim of this rewrite is to preserve the "legacy" behaviour pre-Chrome 80.

Full write-up in my [Coder Frontline blog](https://www.coderfrontline.com/chromes-samesite-cookie-changes-are-breaking-apps/):

```xml
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <preConditions>
      <!-- Checks User Agent to identify browsers incompatible with SameSite=None -->
      <preCondition name="IncompatibleWithSameSiteNone" logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(CPU iPhone OS 12)|(iPad; CPU OS 12)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="(Chrome/5)|(Chrome/6)" />
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="( OS X 10_14).*(Version/).*((Safari)|(KHTML, like Gecko)$)" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>

    <!-- Adds or changes SameSite to None for the session cookie -->
    <!-- Note that secure header is also required by Chrome and should not be added here -->
    <rule name="SessionCookieAddSameSiteNoneHeader">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*ASP.NET_SessionId.*)" />
      <!-- Use this regex if your OS/framework/app adds SameSite=Lax automatically to the end of the cookie -->
      <!-- <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="((.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*))(?=SameSite)" /> -->
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}; SameSite=None" />
    </rule>

    <!-- Removes SameSite=None header from all cookies, for most incompatible browsers -->
    <rule name="CookieRemoveSameSiteNone" preCondition="IncompatibleWithSameSiteNone">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*)(SameSite=None)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

This should work for most ASP .Net and ASP .Net Core applications, although newer Frameworks have proper code and config options to let you control this behaviour. I would recommend researching all the options available to you before using my rewrite above.

Comment: Where do you put this in MVC 5? In ```<system.net></system.net>```?

Comment: In `<system.webServer>`

Comment: Note: if the ASP.NET_SessionId-cookie already has `SameSite=Lax` this will only append `SameSite=None` and not replace it.

Comment: @zemien I don't get why have the `(SameSite=.*)?` at all in the pattern?

Comment: @cederlof I added `(SameSite=.*)?` to the pattern so that it will get replaced with `SameSite=None`. This rectifies the situation of your previous comment where newer .Net updates already add `SameSite=Lax` to the session cookie, by replacing it with the None version. Are you still seeing both SameSite headers even with the regex above?

Comment: @zemien Thanks! SameSite would still be in capture group 1 `{R:1}` from what I can see. https://regex101.com/r/7D9UdO/1

Comment: @cederlof you're right! I didn't test my regex properly because my environment was older .Net framework that did not add the Lax property automatically. In your case, you can use a different regex to exclude `SameSite=Lax` header: `((.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*))(?=SameSite)` See updated https://regex101.com/r/7D9UdO/3 - however note that this regex will exclude anything you may want afterwards, such as the secure header. This should be a rare condition so the key point is to see what your OS+framework+app is emitting and write the regex to suit. I will update my answer to reflect both ways :)

Comment: Worked perfectly form me. I used:           <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}; SameSite=Strict; Secure=true;" />

Answer (score 10):

**Last update:**
[zemien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60357945/7780428) is more comprehensive and complete than mine. because it sets cookie based on user agent.

My Answer:

You can replace SameSite=Lax with SameSite=None for ASP.NET_SessionId in web.config following way:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="AddSameSiteCookieFlag">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="((.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*))(SameSite=Lax)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1};SameSite=None" />
    </rule>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

**Update:**
To prevent [IOS problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269476/browser-wont-set-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-on-payment-gateways-post-request-to), replace

```
<action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1};SameSite=None" />
```

with

```
<action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1};" />
```

Comment: This is possible only if IIS rewriting module is installed on the server

Comment: Your update for iOS problem will also cause problems in newer OSes. Basically speaking, some browsers/OS will assign SameSite=Lax if it is missing the SameSite header. I believe the only way is to do UserAgent sniffing and decide whether to include the header or not. I'm still researching if this can be done via web.config or it has to include a code change in Session_Start.

Comment: Just to highlight what @zemien writes, your iOS-update fixes one problem but introduces another.

Comment: Why setting to None instead of strict?

Comment: @VincentDucroquet  Do you know the "IIS rewriting module" charge fee or not when we install it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

@zemien your solution correctly solved our google chrome issues

We have an integration where our application is embedded in an iframe on a third party. Chrome version 80 released Feb 4 2020 prevented cookies from loading.

However I had to modify the pattern to capture all cookies, add the Secure flag, and condition to not apply the rewrite on localhost for our local non https environment

```
<rule name="SessionCookieAddNoneHeader">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="(.*)(SameSite=.*)?" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1}; SameSite=None; Secure" />
</rule>
```

Comment: This "almost" worked for me, I had to replace the pattern="(.*)(SameSite=.*)?" section with the pattern="(.*ASP.NET_SessionId.*)" from zemien's answer.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: where do you add this rule?

Comment: in our case it is web.config 
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<outboundRules>
<rule name="SessionCookieAddNoneHeader">

Answer (score 5):

Works for me. 
Added into my web.config file :

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None"></sessionState>
```

Upgrade to .Net Framework 4.8 + installation patch : 
2019-12 Cumulative Update for .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.8 for Windows 10 Version 1909 for x64 (KB4533002)

Answer (score 4):

4 machines with google chrome one would not work with cookies across sites on asp.
Folow H. J. van der Wijk info for web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms cookieSameSite="None" />
    </authentication>
```

still did not work, had to change

```
<httpCookies sameSite="None"/>
```

for

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" sameSite="None"/>
```

and all worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add these options to web.config for sameSite=None , Lax or Strict

```
<system.web>
    <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
    <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms cookieSameSite="None" requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

This is supported since .Net Framework 4.7.2.

[Docs on sessionState cookieSameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookiesamesite?view=netframework-4.8)
[Docs on httpCookies sameSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpcookiessection.samesite?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Configuration_HttpCookiesSection_SameSite)
`SameSite=None` requires `Secure` (`requireSSL="true"`). `Lax` and `Strict` don't. `sessionState` doesn't have `requireSSL` and uses attribute from `httpCookies`.
[Good article with explanation of SameSite in Google Chrome](https://blog.heroku.com/chrome-changes-samesite-cookie). Chrome blocks third-party cookie in iframe since version 80.