# ASP.NET_SessionId not found in OWIN OpenIdConnectAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

**BackGround** : User once logged in to the our Web Application (using App level credential) will be presented with with Mail System they want to use based on that user will be redirected to respective authorization server to authenticate (using login / password of their mail system) and the auth server will return an access token back.

In Notification events like OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync or OnAuthenticationFailedAsync; we are not getting **ASP.NET_SessionId** so having said that i am not able to use any of the session values which are set before OAuth Flow.

Refer below Code for more details.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .ClientId = appId,
            .ClientSecret = appSecret,
            .Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
            .Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {ewsScopes}",
            .RedirectUri = redirectUri,
            .PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,            
            .TokenValidationParameters = New TokenValidationParameters With {
                .ValidateIssuer = False
            },
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = AddressOf OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                .AuthorizationCodeReceived = AddressOf OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
            }
        })
```

I am not able to get any session values in HttpConext.Current.Session which are set before OAuth flow in notification events.

As per below SO; i tried different approaches like SystemWebCookieManager, UseKentorOwinCookieSaver but issue not resolved.
[ASP.NET_SessionId + OWIN Cookies do not send to browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737578/asp-net-sessionid-owin-cookies-do-not-send-to-browser)

What could be the issue and how can I resolve it?

Comment: I think this SO answer might help you out. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565543/can-owin-middleware-use-the-http-session)

Comment: @Borka - i tried this but did not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ByDefault; OpenIDConnect uses form post redirects which are incompatible with SameSite. Due to that Application Session cookie not sent over and that is how it should be.

As per couple of Stack overflow link below; using either URL rewrite or below web.config allows us to maintain session when response is posted back to Callback url but we still need to use Owin's SystemWebCookieManager for that in order to work.

[Browser won't set ASP.NET_SessionId cookie on payment gateway's post request to our site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59269476/browser-wont-set-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-on-payment-gateways-post-request-to)

[how SameSite attribute added to my Asp.net_SessionID cookie automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59117357/how-samesite-attribute-added-to-my-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-automatically)

Considering above scenario; for OpenIDConnect Authentication; setting samesite cookie to none and secure; that should work but i afraid that would raise CSRF (Cross site request Forgery) vulnerability for application.

Hence, An alternative is to switch to the Code response type which uses HTTP redirects and works with SameSite=Lax. Set the appropriate code response mode and response type.

ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Query;

ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/blob/635c92f641ad1e014eead31cc7a365004949fda5/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions.cs#L65-L66

Comment: I'm trying your Mode.Query with a .NET 4.8 web app and it redirects to keycloak and then back. But once I'm back at the app, it says Token is null. Was working with the post method. Keycloak logs say code_to_token error, invalid_code