# Session state not maintaining while accessing site from cordova (android/ios webview) or Chrome > 80 after windows 10 update

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, cordova, cookies, webview

Session Id keep changing in each request while accessing the asp.net mvc application from cordova (android/ios webview).
This happened only after **windows 10 update**, before it was working fine.

Session works fine when i try to access from chrome/firefox browser with phonegap windows client, but it's not working if I installed the app in android/ios device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59300799/1019435

In web.config add the blow line under system.web
Have to install [URL Rewrite](https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/8/128E2E22-C1B9-44A4-BE2A-5859ED1D4592/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi) for IIS.

```
 <rewrite>
    <outboundRules>
      <rule name="AddSameSiteCookieFlag">
        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="((.*)(ASP.NET_SessionId)(=.*))(SameSite=Lax)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:1};SameSite=" />
      </rule>
    </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

or

```
<sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
```